# plotting a projection of a circle on a plane

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot the 3D-plot in the first example here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#Examples. I've managed to plot the surface:

```
[x,y]=meshgrid(-3:0.2:3);
z=x+y;
mesh(x,y,z)
```

Any ideas on how to project the circle on the surface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p=0:pi/100:2*pi
%parametric form of a circle
cx=3*cos(p)
cy=3*sin(p)
%project the same way
cz=cx+cy
plot3(cx,cy,cz)
```

Comment: `cis`? `cy=R*cos(p)`?

Comment: you are confusing `sin` and `cosine`. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions

Comment: @Shai: Creates a circle in both ways, but I changed it to the common order.

Comment: the circle is the same circle, but you changed `x` and `y` - it will cause problems when you try to project it onto the surface (unless the surface is symmetric). Try projecting onto `z = 2*x + y`.